# Convert string (word) to long

Tags: c#, .net, string, casting, type-conversion

I want to create a unique ID from a string like "Testcase1", "Testcase2" and so on. Therefore I want to convert the string to a integer respectively a long.

I've tried this, but I think the number/ID is neither unique nor is this method correct. I want to convert the entire word into a number.

```
long numberId = 0;
foreach (var character in testString.ToCharArray())
{
    numberId +=  Convert.ToInt16(character);
}
```

Comment: could you give a sample input / output? Currently you sum up the ASCII value of each character `long numberId = testString.Sum(x => x);`

Comment: When you just add character values, both "AB" and "BA" will give the same result

Comment: You wan to convert character to ascii code?

Comment: @Hans I know, that's exactly my problem. AB and BA are the same.

I thought C # might provide a way to convert a whole word into a number.

Comment: How about `long numberId = testString.GetHashCode();` ?

Comment: The number of possible strings is way higher than the number of ints or longs . So it cannot be unique

Comment: You should consider to Base64 Encode your Testcase value.  It's better than trying to reduce it to an integer. As the other stackers said, the sequence of the letters matters so a numeric value will not suffice.

Comment: How about using something like `Dictionary<string, long> ids` and having a method like `GetOrCreateId(string item) { if (ids.TryGetValue(item, out long id) { return id; } id = ids.Values.Max() + 1; ids[item] = id; return id; }`? - Of course the `id` is not directly *tied* to the `string`. But maybe it's enough for your use case. -- also, as Hans pointed out: beware of pigeonhole!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create();
var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test case");
var hash = sha.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
var result = BitConverter.ToInt64(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have proof but I think following method will generate unique value.

```
public static void Main()
{
    long numberId = 0;
    var testString = "Testcase3";
    long multiplier = (long)Math.Pow(10,testString.Length);
    foreach (var character in testString.ToCharArray())
    {
        numberId +=  Convert.ToInt16(character)*multiplier;
        multiplier /=10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(numberId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {          

            var inputText = "Testcase1";
            Console.WriteLine($"{inputText} =>{CalculateTotal(GetHashString(string.Concat(inputText,DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(),  DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString())).ToArray<char>())}");
            inputText = "Testcase2";
            Console.WriteLine($"{inputText} =>{CalculateTotal(GetHashString(string.Concat(inputText,DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(),  DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString())).ToArray<char>())}");


        }
        static string GetHashString(string inputText)
        {
            HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
            var bytes = new byte[inputText.Length];
            bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputText);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString( hash.ComputeHash(bytes));
        }

        static long CalculateTotal(char [] items)
        {

            var i = Array.ConvertAll<char, long>(items, Convert.ToInt64);
            return i.Sum();             
        }
```

output:

Testcase1 =>1880

Testcase2 =>1788

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be unique then long won't work, because there are more strings than can fit into a long. If you *really* need a unique number, you could use the constructor of `System.Numerics.BigInteger` that takes a byte array, e.g.

```
var id = new BigInteger(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("string goes here"));
```

Depending on what you're doing, this may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this implementation using the sum of byte array based on the test string:

```
    long uniqueId = "Testcase1".SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray().Sum(c=> c);
    long uniqueId2 = "Testcase2".SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray().Sum(c => c);
```

Testcase1 ->877

Testcase2 ->878